# Transform Pandas dataframe based on all possible combinations of a column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe which tracks customer basket data. Time interval is weekly, ie for every customer, there are rows for items bought(if any) during that week. So if a customer buys 3 items on week1, the dataframe will have 3 rows for that customer for week1. The below example shows 2 customers who bought various items on certain weeks.

```
data = [['1011', 1, 'Week-1','item1'],
        ['1011', 2, 'Week-2','item1'],
        ['1011', 3, 'Week-3','item2'],
        ['1011', 3, 'Week-3','item30'],
        ['1011', 5, 'Week-5','item12'],
        ['1022', 10, 'Week-10','item8'],
        ['1022', 10, 'Week-10','item12'],
        ['1022', 16, 'Week-16','item1'],
        ['1022', 17, 'Week-17','item2'],
       ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['CustomerID', 'WeekID', 'Weekname','ProductID'])
print(df)

    CustomerID  WeekID  Weekname    ProductID
0   1011           1    Week-1      item1
1   1011           2    Week-2      item1
2   1011           3    Week-3      item2
3   1011           3    Week-3      item30
4   1011           5    Week-5      item12
5   1022           10   Week-10     item8
6   1022           10   Week-10     item12
7   1022           16   Week-16     item1
8   1022           17   Week-17     item2
```

I want to list all possible combination of weeks for every customer and repopulate the dataframe based on these combinations. In my example, customer 1011, will have the following week combinations.
Week1->Week5, Week1->Week3 and Week1->Week2.
I am ignoring all combinations are are single rows, in this case Week1->Week1 is ignored.

The output dataframe should look like this for the 2 customers.

```
CustomerID-FromWeekID-ToWeekID  CustomerID   WeekID Weekname  ProductID
1011-1-5                        1011         1      Week-1    item1
1011-1-5                        1011         2      Week-2    item1
1011-1-5                        1011         3      Week-3    item2
1011-1-5                        1011         3      Week-3    item30
1011-1-5                        1011         5      Week-5    item12
1011-1-3                        1011         1      Week-1    item1
1011-1-3                        1011         2      Week-2    item1
1011-1-3                        1011         3      Week-3    item2
1011-1-3                        1011         3      Week-3    item30
1011-1-2                        1011         1      Week-1    item1
1011-1-2                        1011         2      Week-2    item1
1022-10-17                      1022         10     Week-10   item8
1022-10-17                      1022         10     Week-10   item12
1022-10-17                      1022         16     Week-16   item1
1022-10-17                      1022         17     Week-17   item2
1022-10-16                      1022         10     Week-10   item8
1022-10-16                      1022         10     Week-10   item12
1022-10-16                      1022         16     Week-16   item1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ['1011', 1, 'Week-1','item1'],
    ['1011', 2, 'Week-2','item1'],
    ['1011', 3, 'Week-3','item2'],
    ['1011', 3, 'Week-3','item30'],
    ['1011', 5, 'Week-5','item12'],
    ['1022', 10, 'Week-10','item8'],
    ['1022', 10, 'Week-10','item12'],
    ['1022', 16, 'Week-16','item1'],
    ['1022', 17, 'Week-17','item2'],
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['CustomerID', 'WeekID', 'Weekname','ProductID'])

all_data = []
for customer, group in df.groupby('CustomerID'):
    unique_weeks = sorted(group['WeekID'].unique())
    start_week = unique_weeks[0]
    for end_week in unique_weeks[1:]:
        subset = group[(group['WeekID'] >= start_week) & (group['WeekID'] <= end_week)].copy()
        subset['CustomerID-FromWeekID-ToWeekID'] = f"{customer}-{start_week}-{end_week}"
        all_data.append(subset)

new_df = pd.concat(all_data)
new_df = new_df[['CustomerID-FromWeekID-ToWeekID', 'CustomerID', 'WeekID', 'Weekname', 'ProductID']]
new_df = new_df.reset_index(drop=True)
print(new_df.to_markdown())
```

Output:

| CustomerID-FromWeekID-ToWeekID | CustomerID | WeekID | Weekname | ProductID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1011-1-2 | 1011 | 1 | Week-1 | item1 |
| 1011-1-2 | 1011 | 2 | Week-2 | item1 |
| 1011-1-3 | 1011 | 1 | Week-1 | item1 |
| 1011-1-3 | 1011 | 2 | Week-2 | item1 |
| 1011-1-3 | 1011 | 3 | Week-3 | item2 |
| 1011-1-3 | 1011 | 3 | Week-3 | item30 |
| 1011-1-5 | 1011 | 1 | Week-1 | item1 |
| 1011-1-5 | 1011 | 2 | Week-2 | item1 |
| 1011-1-5 | 1011 | 3 | Week-3 | item2 |
| 1011-1-5 | 1011 | 3 | Week-3 | item30 |
| 1011-1-5 | 1011 | 5 | Week-5 | item12 |
| 1022-10-16 | 1022 | 10 | Week-10 | item8 |
| 1022-10-16 | 1022 | 10 | Week-10 | item12 |
| 1022-10-16 | 1022 | 16 | Week-16 | item1 |
| 1022-10-17 | 1022 | 10 | Week-10 | item8 |
| 1022-10-17 | 1022 | 10 | Week-10 | item12 |
| 1022-10-17 | 1022 | 16 | Week-16 | item1 |
| 1022-10-17 | 1022 | 17 | Week-17 | item2 |